# Power BI can't access Godaddy's Database

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I have hosted SQL Server database in Godaddy servers, and I am using Power BI desktop at the moment.

I can connect to my godaddy's database through SSMS

but when I try through MS Power BI I get this error

[image]

I was sure that credentials are correct

and I can connect to my local database

I called Godaddy's support and they informed me that there is no blockage or any issue from there side and the problem is from within Power BI

especially that other people can connect through Power BI

so I wonder if anyone know what is the reason that could stop Power BI connecting to Godaddy's database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason
it was that I was using Windows connection method
I should use Database

[image]